# Floating Icon on Home - What is this called?

Tags: home-screen, volume-buttons

My volume keys are dead because of some of my stupid mistakes. So I have downloaded a Volume button assist app, that always displays + and - buttons that simulate the volume button behaviour.

[image]

I checked and the app is sharing my activities with some other org and I dont want that.

I thought it can be easily built. I want to know what it is called so that I can read some documentation.

Comment: I assume it is not an `Activity`

Comment: My guess is that those buttons are placed on a system overlay window that is shown always on top.

Comment: Okay. And how do we create a system overlay window?